# What types need to be used for withAuthenticator in a Typescript, Amplify, React application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-amplify

What **types** should you use in a Amplify-Typescript-React application when using `withAuthenticator`?

There are only js examples in the docs: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator

Using this works but I have to suppress a number of warnings:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    ...
  },
});

function App({ user }) { ... // TS7031 any type - what about isPassedToWithAuthenticator or signOut?

export default withAuthenticator(App); // TS2345 warning
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This is the PR which introduced this "problem": https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/pull/1724 ... I asked there the PR creator to provide some guidance, either there or here in SO.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import {
  withAuthenticator,
  WithAuthenticatorProps,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const App = ({ signOut, user }: WithAuthenticatorProps) => {};
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer adding additional informations explaining what the code do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in love with this answer, but in the absence of guidance from the documentation, this is the best solution I came up with for the same problem, without having to suppress any warnings.

```
type LoggedInProps = {
  appRoute: string;
  cookies: any;
  user: any;
  /* ...other passed props... */
  signOut: any;
};

// This component houses the logged-in state of the app.
const LoggedInBody = withAuthenticator((props:any) => {
  const { 
    appRoute, cookies, user, /* other stuff, */ signOut
  }:LoggedInProps = props;

  /*rest of component goes here */
}
```

That way I'm still validating that the props that get passed are the right ones, while getting past TS2345.